# Does unnecessary inclusion of commercial link in a question count as spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

There's a recent question (which I didn't provide a link to initially) from someone doing SEO (search engine optimisation) for a client. The question isn't brilliant (could probably be closed as too broad, or opinion based) but ends with a link to the site they are promoting.

Should this be marked as spam?

There are many posts on meta warning against *overusing* the Spam flag... I would say it's not explicitly *gratuitous advertising* (there *is* a question in there, albeit a poor one), and it's not an *undisclosed affiliation* (the OP says they're doing SEO for this company).

However, including the link to the site serves *no* purpose as far as answering the question is concerned, and, while the OP may appreciate any SEO tips someone provides, as far as I can see the main point of the question is to include the link.

---

In the end (perhaps slightly prematurely), I flagged the post in question as spam, which was deemed "helpful" and the post got deleted ([link for those with 10k+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323229/want-to-get-website-traffic-from-multiple-countries) -- I don't so cannot provide an image).

Comment: SEO isn't on-topic for SO and links to SEO companies (however subtle) in pretty much all cases is just to put the link across...

Comment: Thanks.for the quick response. I'll flag it as spam then.

Comment: @TripeHound: We didn't say it was spam *per se* however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, but while mindful of the exhortation not to over-use the spam-flag, Jon's response ("_in pretty much all cases is just to put the link across_") was enough to nudge it from "balanced either way" into the spam-camp. If that turns out wrong, I apologise in advance.

Comment: @TripeHound: as tripleee states below: *it depends*. First time poster with 'We do SEO' all over their profile asking a question along the lines of  'here is this site, isn't it great? We did the SEO job on it, can we tweak it a bit more?' is spam. A question that happens to be off-topic where the question asker thinks that the link is extra helpful context for their question, is not spam. Even if the question is about SEO.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The flag has now been deemed "helpful" and the post deleted so I'll add the link to the question. To me it was between those last two cases: it was a nearly first-time poster, but not SEO all over their profile; the off-topic question included a link, but I can't believe the poster (innocently) thought it would provide context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think there is a cut and dried consensus on this, nor is it likely that one can be reached, IMHO.  I'll try to outline the status quo to my best understanding, but the bottom line in this answer is really "it depends".

Many questions contain tangential information which detracts from the actual question, and in normal cases, the recommended course of action is to edit the question into shape by removing those tangential passages.  However, caution should be exercised when removing what appears to be promotional links.  Are you *sure* the post is really adding value to the site if you elide the non-promotional part?  Editing a very low quality post into a more *focused* VLQ is a waste of effort and unnecessarily bumps the post.

Furthermore, removing a promotional link may obscure a spam attempt -- if the same user posts multiple promotional links in different posts, that is a clear signal that the poster is a spammer, but if some of those posts are edited into nominally acceptable posts, some of the evidence to take action against the account is lost, or at least made harder to collect.

My concrete guidance would be to leave the post alone if you are unsure.  Maybe a picture will form down the line to help us reach a conclusive verdict.